# Found this inside an orange. No rot or any other marks on the skin. Does anyone know what this is?

Tags: identification

Can anyone identify this bizarre thing inside of an orange?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This could be black rot caused by *Alternaria citri*, a fungus. Read more about it [here](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/fruits/citrus/citrus-alternaria-rot.htm). The unripe fruit gets infected through small damages during humid weather. And the fungus will spread inside the fruit later, also during storage.